# Возможно ли притормозить пинг?

Tags: сеть, ping, icmp

Возможно ли притормозить пинг непосредственно на компьютере клиента? 
Возможно ли притормозить входящие пакеты данных? Входящий пинг?

**Обновление**

Пакет данных от меня до сервера и обратно проходит за 2 мс, возможно ли на стадии возвращения с сервера притормозить его, ну, скажем, на 100 мс?

Comment: Всегда считал, что ping - это замер времени между отправкой и получением сигнала или данных. Не очень понятно, что значит "входящий пинг на компьютере клиента".

Comment: @Get, как это исключает возможность его увеличить?

Comment: Пакет данных от меня до сервера и обратно проходит за 2 мс, возможно ли на стадии возвращения с сервера притормозить его ну скажем на 100 мс?

Comment: проксируйте и тормозите запрос на прокси сервере.
Но зачем?

Comment: Если клиент линуксовый, то можно использовать утилиту `tc`. С её помощью проще управлять исходящим трафиком, но с помощью виртуального интерфейса можно задержать и входящий трафик [tc](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#How_can_I_use_netem_on_incoming_traffic.3F).